# C++11 new feature of delegating constructors in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I'm trying to use the new C++11 feature by using visual studio 2012. I don't really know if I'm not using it right or I need to add this feature to the visual studio?

```
struct Student{
  Student(double avgGrade, double avgProject): _avgGrade(avgGrade),_avgProject(avgProject){…}
  Student() : Student(0,0){…}
  Student(double avgGrade) : Student(avgGrade,0){…}
   private:
    double _avgGrade;
    double _avgProject;
};
```

Comment: IIRC, only the CTP in 2012 supports that.

Comment: But you're not using it. You're just using regular old constructor initialization lists.

Comment: This is an c++11 feature, and it doesn't work in my visual studio 2012

Comment: Are you referring to the constructors calling the other constructors? That is called delegating constructors, not non-static data member initializers. Non-static data member initializers is when you give default values to your members inside the class body, not as part of any constructor.

Comment: Well, I can't remember if delegating constructors were supported in the 2012 CTP as well, but I'm fairly sure in-class member initializers were. If you can't use 2013 and you don't mind using a CTP, there's an option.

Comment: I took the liberty of making the title match the question. I hope this is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delegating constructors are [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) out of the box in Visual Studio 2012. You can, however, install the [Visual C++ Compiler November 2012 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515), which, among other things, introduces support for delegating constructors.

After installing, you need to set your project to use the CTP as toolset. To do this, right click on the project file and select `Properties`. Under `Configuration Properties -> General` find the `Platform Toolset` entry. Set it to `Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2012 CTP (v120_CTP_Nov2012),` which should be an entry in the combo box.

Comment: how do I set my project to use CTP?

Comment: @GuyGuetta I've edited the answer to include how to set your project to use the CTP.